# V8 compilation problems

Tags: macos, gcc, v8

I'm trying to compile a file with the V8 the JavaScript Engine by Google. I installed `scons` and have compiled the V8 engine. But, here is where the problem lies, I stay in the V8 directory as they say and make a file named `hello_world.cpp` with the code:

```
#include <v8.h>

using namespace v8;

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

      // Create a stack-allocated handle scope.
      HandleScope handle_scope;

      // Create a new context.
      Persistent<Context> context = Context::New();

      // Enter the created context for compiling and
      // running the hello world script. 
      Context::Scope context_scope(context);

      // Create a string containing the JavaScript source code.
      Handle<String> source = String::New("'Hello' + ', World!'");

      // Compile the source code.
      Handle<Script> script = Script::Compile(source);

      // Run the script to get the result.
      Handle<Value> result = script->Run();

      // Dispose the persistent context.
      context.Dispose();

      // Convert the result to an ASCII string and print it.
      String::AsciiValue ascii(result);
      printf("%s\n", *ascii);
      return 0;
    }
```

Then I compile using `gcc hello_world.cpp -o libv8.a`. But, when I compile it I get a skew of errors:

```
hello_world.cpp:1:16: error: v8.h: No such file or directory
hello_world.cpp:3: error: ‘v8’ is not a namespace-name
hello_world.cpp:3: error: expected namespace-name before ‘;’ token
hello_world.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
hello_world.cpp:8: error: ‘HandleScope’ was not declared in this scope
hello_world.cpp:8: error: expected `;' before ‘handle_scope’
hello_world.cpp:11: error: ‘Persistent’ was not declared in this scope
hello_world.cpp:11: error: ‘Context’ was not declared in this scope
hello_world.cpp:11: error: ‘context’ was not declared in this scope
hello_world.cpp:11: error: ‘Context’ is not a class or namespace
hello_world.cpp:15: error: ‘Context’ is not a class or namespace
hello_world.cpp:15: error: expected `;' before ‘context_scope’
hello_world.cpp:18: error: ‘Handle’ was not declared in this scope
hello_world.cpp:18: error: ‘String’ was not declared in this scope
hello_world.cpp:18: error: ‘source’ was not declared in this scope
hello_world.cpp:18: error: ‘String’ is not a class or namespace
hello_world.cpp:21: error: ‘Script’ was not declared in this scope
hello_world.cpp:21: error: ‘script’ was not declared in this scope
hello_world.cpp:21: error: ‘Script’ is not a class or namespace
hello_world.cpp:24: error: ‘Value’ was not declared in this scope
hello_world.cpp:24: error: ‘result’ was not declared in this scope
hello_world.cpp:30: error: ‘String’ is not a class or namespace
hello_world.cpp:30: error: expected `;' before ‘ascii’
hello_world.cpp:31: error: ‘ascii’ was not declared in this scope
hello_world.cpp:31: error: ‘printf’ was not declared in this scope
```

I don't get why it say V8.h is not declared. I already built it and I'm in its directory and I'm guessing if I get rid of that all the other errors will go away. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i just believe you in that you are really inside the toplevel source directory (and since i do not have compiled v8 i only believe that libvp8.a is created in that toplevel directory):

```
% g++ -Iinclude hello_world.cpp -o hello_world libv8.a
```

1. it says "v8.h" is not declared because that file is inside the "include" directory and the preprocessor is not able to find it out of thin air.
2. furthermore: you are compiling a .cpp file with the C compiler instead of the C++ compiler.
3. you are using the '-o' flag wrong because it defines the name of the linked binary and thus needs a name, you do not want the output binary be named "libvp8.a"